# Unable to deploy Springboot app in Jboss-eap-6.4

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jboss, jboss6.x

i am facing below issue while deploying my springboot app in Jboss server,

Changes done for deploying springboot app in Jboss server

- I have  extended `SpringBootServletInitializer` in my main class
- Excluded `spring-boot-starter-tomcat` from my pom.xml

**Version details**

- Spring boot version 2.1.8.RELEASE
- JBoss server Version 6.4

**ErrorLog**

```
08:09:21,934 ERROR [org.jboss.web] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 53) JBAS018202: Error calling onStartup for servlet container initializer: org.springframework.web.SpringServletContainerInitializer: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'defaultValidator' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/validation/ValidationAutoConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.LocalValidatorFactoryBean]: Factory method 'defaultValidator' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/el/ELManager
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:627) [spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:456) [spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1321) [spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1160) [spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:555) [spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:515) [spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320) [spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
```

i have verified javax.el-api dependency in place at jboss server (< JBOSS _HOME >\modules\system\layers\base\javax\el\api\main)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

seems `JBoss server 6.4` not support `springBoot 2.1.8 RELEASE`. when i downgrade the springboot version to `1.5.22 RELEASE`, i can able to deploy the war file.